# Location service permission(alert) not showing in iPod

Tags: xcode4.5, core-location, ipod-touch, ios6-maps

I have uploaded a GPS based iPhone app(iOS 6) to app store. One of my friend told that, core location permission is not asking for his device(iPod). As his location is not getting updated, he misses the functionalities. I have tried many devices here (iPhone 4S, 5 and iPad), but all get worked nicely. I don't know what is wrong with my app. If any body has idea then please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that the iPod he is testing with is not location capable. If the device is not capable of location updates, it will never prompt the user for location.

I would embed an alert if the device can't use location so the user/tester knows why location updates aren't working.

Newer iPad/iPod Touch devices can get location updates based on the new Wifi tiling, but that functionality (new to iOS 6) is not backwards compatible with older devices. That is why it is best to test for location availability first, then alert if not available.

Comment: Ok. But the thing is, for all other apps in the device it is working fine. Only issue is with this app.

Comment: It is possible that the prompt has already been shown. Maybe they accidentally declined location permission. You can delete the app to reset the warnings, or check location permission under Privacy in settings. Make sure that your app has permission. This all assumes that the device has the correct location abilities.

Answer (score 0):

The API got a update recently (iOS 6) and I remember the way to get the permissions for Location and showing its message (purpose) got deprecated.

Take a look at the docs and find the deprecated stuff.

I hope it helps.